# Angular - Directive Controller - $attrs value as object

Tags: angularjs

I'm fairly new to Angular (3rd day). I have the following view:

```
    <div ng-repeat="keyword in vc.promotionData.keywords">
      <keyword data="keyword"></keyword>
    </div>
```

My `keyword` directive is as follows:

```
promotionApp.directive("keyword", ->
  template = """
      <span class="input-append">
        <input type="text" value="{{data.value}}" ng-model="_value"
        placeholder="Add Search Keyphrase (3-5 words)" class="span12"
        id="appendedInputButton">
        <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="saveKeyword({{data.id}}, {{data.promotion_id}}, _value)">Save</button>
        <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="saveKeyword({{data.id}}, {{data.promotion_id}}, _value)">Delete</button>
      </span>
  """
  return {
    restrict: "E"
    transclude: true
    template: template
    replace: true
    scope: {}
    controller: ($scope, $element, $attrs) ->
      $scope.data = $attrs.data
      $scope.saveKeyword = (id, promotion_id, value) ->
        value ?= ""
        if id and promotion_id
          if value.length is 0
            console.log "saveKeyword::delete"
          else
            console.log "saveKeyword::save #{value}"
  }
)
```

So, what I want to do, is from my HTML view, pass the `keyword` object into directive (keyword being JSON).

Before I added a controller into the directive, I could do it like so:

```
scope: { data:"=" }
```

But with controller, it doesn't work. So my question is, how do I now get `keyword` object from HTML, into the `keyword` directive `$scope` in its controller?

**EDIT**: Actually, scope and controller do work together. My bad.

```
    promotionApp.directive("keyword", ->
  template = """
      <span class="input-append">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.value"
        placeholder="Add Search Keyphrase (3-5 words)" class="span12"
        id="appendedInputButton">
        <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="saveKeyword(data.id, data.promotion_id, data.value)">Save</button>
        <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="saveKeyword(data.id, data.promotion_id, '')">Delete</button>
      </span>
  """
  return {
    restrict: "E"
    transclude: true
    template: template
    replace: true
    scope: { data:"=" }
    controller: ($scope, $element, $attrs) ->
      console.log $scope.data
      $scope.saveKeyword = (id, promotion_id, value) ->
        value ?= ""
        console.log "#{id} #{promotion_id} #{value} "
        if id and promotion_id
          if value.length is 0
            console.log "saveKeyword::delete"
          else
            console.log "saveKeyword::update"
        else if promotion_id and value.length > 0
          console.log "saveKeyword::create"
        $element.remove()
  }
)
```

Comment: `data` should still be available after adding controller. Was it null\undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set up `scope: { data:"=" }`, then you shouldn't set `$scope.data = $attrs.data`.  In fact, if you set `$scope.data = $attrs.data`, then you are setting `$scope.data` to the string value of `"keyword"`, not the object.

By using `scope: {data: '='}`, then `$scope.data` will be bound and will update with any changes to `data`.

Also, don't assume that `$scope.data` will be set when the controller code is initialized.  Depending on how it is uses, it may or may not be there.

You template will bind to `data` as soon as the `'='` binding occurs.

Comment: My bad, I guess I had a bug somewhere. It does work.